# Equivalent of bash's -x debug flag for C programs?

Tags: c

I always use the -x (or debug flag) when it come to bash script, or shell scripts in general.

Now i'm curious to know, is there an equivalent, either using a specific compiler options, (i use gcc, but i don't mind any other compilers) or by using a specific code in my project?

Basically i just wanted a way to emulate what bash does (using the debug flag) which show which command/function was launched first, in order, and also show the output of said function, with additional errors message etc.But for C.

I'm aware of most debug option out there, especially considering the compiler, but i really wish i could do this in my C projects too.(especially the part where it show what is executed in order, like bash does with -x)

NB: There isn't any goal in this specific question beside the question itself, as i'm just curious if this exist, and thus don't have any need for it beside the actual *knowledge* acquired from said answered question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can mimic this behaviour with a debugger.
With GDB for instance you can write "Init Files" and "Command Files" in which you can write a simple loop:

```
break main
run
while 1
next
end
```

If you put a file named .gdbinit in the directory where you start gdb, this file will be executed or gdb will lead you on the way to configure it in order that it will be executed.

The other option is to pipe this file into your gdb-call:

```
gdb a.out < debug_me_like-x
```

Where the "debug_me_like-x" file is the one mentioned above.

As a reference for the "Command Files" have a look [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-Files.html#Command-Files).